# How to transmit a value from Service to Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

I have two java file,one is the `DeviceControl extends Activity` another one is `BluetoothLeService extends Service`.

I call the function in **BluetoothLeService.java**, and I want it return the **rssi** value to **DeviceControl.java**.

I use `mRssi = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI);` in **DeviceControl.java**, and it will receive the value from **rssi** in **BluetoothLeService.java**.

But it always show the **value is null** in **DeviceControl.java**.

Why the value of mRssi is null??

This is the function in **BluetoothLeService.java**

```
        public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {

public final static String ACTION_RSSI_VALUE_READ = "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_RSSI_VALUE_READ";

                                ．
                                ．
                                ．
            public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
}

public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
    //super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
    if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(ACTION_RSSI_VALUE_READ);               
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_RSSI_VALUE_READ, rssi);
            //call and send the intent and rssi to broadcastUpdate function
    }
}

//broadcastUpdate function receive the intent and rssi value, and transmit to the DeviceControl.java by using sendBroadcast.
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action, final int rssi) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    intent.putExtra(DeviceControl.EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI, rssi);
    Log.v(TAG, "rssi action = " + action);
    Log.v(TAG, "RSSI = " + rssi);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
        for(byte byteChar : data)
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X", byteChar));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

And the code in **DeviceControl.java**

```
public class DeviceControl extends Activity {

public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI = "DEVICE_RSSI";
private String mRssi;

private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final String action = intent.getAction();

　　　　　　　　　final Intent intent = getIntent();
                 mRssi = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI);　//Use **mRssi** to receive the value from BluetoothLeService.java 
                 Log.d(TAG, "mRssi = " + mRssi);

　　　　　　　　　if(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnect = true;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnect = false;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }  else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_RSSI_VALUE_READ.equals(action)) {
            mRssi = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI);
            Log.v(TAG, "mRssi == :" + mRssi);
        }//if the action is EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI, receive the rssi value
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

the code in **BluetoothLeService.java**
modify the code of **onReadRemoteRssi** and **broadcastUpdate**.

the code in **DeviceControl.java**
add the code of receive value from intent in **onReceive**

I see the log from log file, it has show the log message at broadcastUpdate function in **BluetoothLeService.java** like the following:

```
Log.v(TAG, "rssi action = " + action);
Log.v(TAG, "RSSI = " + rssi);
```

But I didn't saw any log about **action = EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI**.
I don't know is the sendBroadcast doesn't send or the **onReceive** doesn't called ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like this, Add the **Action** before Broadcast.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(DeviceControl.EXTRAS_DEVICE_RSSI, rssi);
intent.setAction(YOUR_INTENT_FILETR);  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Can I have two onReceivce in DeviceControl.java to receive different Intent from BluetoothLeService.java ???

Comment: @MartinWun for that you need two different Intent-Filter to identify which BroadcastRecieve recieve your message.

Comment: I have edit the code , I send the intent by use sendBroadcast. But the receiver doesn't receive the intent.

Comment: I have solve this problem after I add the intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_RSSI_VALUE_READ);

But now I have to solve the problem of type of following log:
W/Bundle  ( 4741): Key DEVICE_RSSI expected String but value was a java.lang.Int
eger.  The default value <null> was returned.
W/Bundle  ( 4741): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
W/Bundle  ( 4741): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cas
t to java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the intent that creates the activity, but not the broadcast intent, so of course it is null......